# Why does select into fail when I specify a second column name when creating an event in mySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When creating an event, why do I get `Undeclared variable: voteType` when I add a second column to the select sql? Is it not possible to specify a second column in the sql statement? What's the right way to do this?

```
BEGIN

DECLARE c VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE vElm INT(10);
DECLARE vType TINYINT(1);

select distinct(country) into c from votes;

select votedElm into vElm, voteType into vType from votes where country = c;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `INTO` syntax in your second case is expecting a variable *array* as the destination. It's seeing `vElm, voteType` as the array of variables, but since `voteType` hasn't been declared as one (because it's really one of your columns), you get an exception. Try it this way instead:

```
select <columns> into <variables> from ...
```

In your case:

```
select votedElm, voteType into vElm, vType from votes where country = c;
```

There are examples in the [MySQL reference for `INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html).

Comment: You solution worked. Just one small thing. Will `c` in the event given the value of the country or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Can you re-phrase? If the first query returns more than one distinct country then both queries will fail.

Comment: In my event, I've used `select distinct(country) into c from votes;`, Will `c` give me the name of country from the table so I can use it in the sql below it?